# Overloading operators with C++ metaprogramming templates

Tags: c++, performance, template-meta-programming

I'm using some template meta-programming to solve a small problem, but the syntax is a little annoying -- so I was wondering, in the example below, will overloading operators on the meta-class that has an empty constructor cause a (run-time) performance penalty? Will all the temporaries actually be constructed or can it be assumed that they will be optimized out?

```
template<int value_>
struct Int {
    static const int value = value_;

    template<typename B>
    struct Add : public Int<value + B::value> {  };

    template<typename B>
    Int<value + B::value> operator+(B const&) { return Int<value + B::value>(); }
};

int main()
{
    // Is doing this:
    int sum = Int<1>::Add<Int<2> >().value;

    // any more efficient (at runtime) than this:
    int sum = (Int<1>() + Int<2>()).value;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `Int<1>::Add<Int<2>>().value` can be re-written as `Int<1>::Add<Int<2>>::value`.

Comment: Oh. I seem to be creating [expression templates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2598596/21475) without even knowing it. Seems the optimizers are pretty good at handling this sort of thing!

Comment: @Nawaz: You're right of course, that's an artifact of the design of my real code (which eventually needs an instance at run-time).

Comment: I believe `Add<>` approach is likely to be faster, or at least not slower than `+` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare assembly code generated by g++ -O3 -S for both solutions. It gives same code for both solutions. It actually optimize code to simply return 3.

Comment: Yep, just did that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I tried my example under GCC.

For the `Add` version with no optimization (`-O0`), the resulting assembly just loads a constant into sum, then returns it.

For the `operator+` version with no optimization (`-O0`), the resulting assembly does a bit more (it appears to be calling `operator+`).

However, with `-O3`, both versions generate the same assembly, which simply loads `3` directly into the return register; the temporaries, function calls, and `sum` had been optimized out entirely in both cases.

So, **they're equally fast** with a decent compiler (as long as optimizations are turned on).