# `operator<<` on comma separated values in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, operator-overloading, comma-operator

The following syntax is working in OpenCV

```
Mat R = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
        1,          0,           0, 0,
        0, cos(alpha), -sin(alpha), 0,
        0, sin(alpha),  cos(alpha), 0,
        0,          0,           0, 1);
```

How it can be? What operator was overloaded? What is the sense of this expression?  Does comma operator can be overloaded in nowadays `C++`?

Comment: yep, the comma operator can be overloaded. The only ones you can't overload are the scope resolution op (`::`), the dot (`.`) and the ternary op (`?:`).

Comment: You need to look into the code. Maybe it's using [expression templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598579/c-expression-templates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comma operator can be overloaded, although it is typically not recommended (in many cases the overloaded comma is confusing).

The expression above defines 16 values for 4*4 matrix. If you are wondering how this is possible, I'll show a simpler example. Suppose we want to be able to write something like

```
MyVector<double> R = (MyVector<double>() << 1 , 2 , 3);
```

then we can define MyVector so that `<<` and `,` operators append new value to the vector:

```
template<typename T> 
class MyVector: public std::vector<T> {
 public:
  MyVector<T>& operator << (T value) { push_back(value); return *this; }
  MyVector<T>& operator , (T value) { push_back(value); return *this; }
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the actual code [taken from here](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/mat_8hpp_source.html), as you can see the `operator,` is  being used:

```
template<typename _Tp> template<typename T2> inline MatCommaInitializer_<_Tp>&
MatCommaInitializer_<_Tp>::operator , (T2 v)
{
     CV_DbgAssert( this->it < ((const Mat_<_Tp>*)this->it.m)->end() );
     *this->it = _Tp(v); ++this->it;
    return *this;
}
```

It takes the next value and simply puts it in the matrix, increments the iterator and then returns a reference to the `MatCommaInitializer` object (so these operators can be chained together).

Answer (score 2):

Below is the source code of OpenCV. We can know the class MatCommaInitializer_ overloaded the `,` operator, and overloaded the `<<` operator in the global static field.

```
`
core.hpp
...
template<typename _Tp> class MatCommaInitializer_
{
public:
    //! the constructor, created by "matrix << firstValue" operator, where matrix is cv::Mat
    MatCommaInitializer_(Mat_<_Tp>* _m);
    //! the operator that takes the next value and put it to the matrix
    template<typename T2> MatCommaInitializer_<_Tp>& operator , (T2 v);
    //! another form of conversion operator
    Mat_<_Tp> operator *() const;
    operator Mat_<_Tp>() const;
protected:
    MatIterator_<_Tp> it;
};
...
`

`
mat.hpp
...
template<typename _Tp, typename T2> static inline MatCommaInitializer_<_Tp>
operator << (const Mat_<_Tp>& m, T2 val)
{
    MatCommaInitializer_<_Tp> commaInitializer((Mat_<_Tp>*)&m);
    return (commaInitializer, val);
}
...
`
```

So the working process of your code is as follows:

1. Mat_(4, 4) creates an instance that contains 4 row 4 column elements of double type.
2. It then calls the `<<` overloaded operator and returns MatCommaInitializer_ instance.
3. It then calls the `,` overloaded operator and returns MatCommaInitializer_ instance, and so on.
4. Finally calls the constructor `Mat(const MatCommaInitializer_<_Tp>& commaInitializer)`