# How many temporary objects are created when two objects are added together without the return value optimization?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, copy-elision, return-value-optimization, effective-c++

I decided to ask this question after reading items 20 and 22 of the book "More Effective C++" by Scott Meyers.

Let's say you wrote a class to represent rational numbers:

```cpp
class Rational
{
public:
    Rational(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1);

    int numerator() const;
    int denominator() const;

    Rational& operator+=(const Rational& rhs); // Does not create any temporary objects
    ...
};
```

Now let's say that you decided to implement `operator+` using `operator+=`:

```cpp
const Rational operator+(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs)
{
    return Rational(lhs) += rhs;
}
```

My question is: if the *return value optimization* were disabled, how many temporary variables would be created by `operator+`?

```cpp
Rational result, a, b;
...
result = a + b;
```

I believe 2 temporaries are created: one when `Rational(lhs)` is executed inside the body of `operator+`, and another when the value returned by `operator+` is created by copying the first temporary.

My confusion arose when Scott presented this operation:

```cpp
Rational result, a, b, c, d;
...
result = a + b + c + d;
```

And wrote: "Probably uses 3 temporary objects, one for each call to `operator+`". I believe that if the *return value optimization* were disabled, the operation above would use 6 temporary objects (2 for each call to `operator+`), while if it were enabled, the operation above would use no temporaries at all. How did Scott arrive at his result? I think the only way to do so would be to partially apply the *return value optimization*.

Comment: You can instrument the destructor (have it print something), and this way count how many temporaries are actually created by your compiler. However, you would be hard-pressed to find a compiler where you can disable RVO; all modern compilers I know of perform it unconditionally, even in debug builds with optimizations disabled. Moreover, C++17 standard makes RVO mandatory, rendering the question unequivocally moot.

Comment: do not return `const Rational` - I mean skip `const` (but not related to question)

Comment: This is a nice question (+1) but I dislike the sentiment intensely. You are asking a "what happens if a soon-to-be-compulsory" feature of C++ is disabled?

Comment: *How many temporary variables would be created by operator+* -- Doesn't this really depend on the compiler, even if you were able to turn off RVO?  A "bad" compiler may create more temporaries than a "good" compiler, but still achieve the same end result.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I think there is an upper limit especially if the constructor or destructor has side-effects.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- If the quote from the OP is correct, it looks like even Scott M. isn't sure -- *Probably uses 3 temporary objects,* -- the keyword being "Probably".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I'm hoping that the great Scott M. is using "Probably" to mean "Upper bounded by".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The quote is taken directly from page 108 of the book.

Comment: @Bathsheba wouldn't the upper bound be 6 temporaries?

Comment: @user3266738: Strictly no more than 3, by my reading. The expression is grouped as ((a + b) + c) + d

Comment: @Bathsheba But what about the temporaries created inside `operator+` when `Rational(lhs)` is executed to be able to call `operator+=`? If you consider those, the upper bound is 6? Or are those optimized out of existence in some way?

Comment: @user3266738: FYI: "*if the return value optimization were disabled, how many temporary variables would be created by operator+?*" The same number as would be created if RVO were enabled.

Comment: Assuming no RVO: (a+b) creates a temporary and creates another to be passed to (b + c), (b+c) creates a temporary and another to be passed to (c+d), (c+d) creates a temporary and another which is assigned to result. That leads to 6 temporaries. The key thing to note is that ((a+b) + c) will pass the result of (a+b) directly to `operator+` even without RVO since it's passed by const reference, not by value. Meanwhile with RVO, all those "return and pass somewhere else" temps are eliminated, and you end up with half the temporaries.

Comment: Not saying that's how things actually work but probably how he arrived at the estimate of "probably 6 temporaries" without RVO. There's no "partial RVO" required to pass the result of `operator+` to another invocation of `operator+` provided the operands are accepted by const ref. There's a temp involved local to the function, another to return without RVO, but not another to pass the result as an operand to another call to `operator+`.

Comment: So that leads to 3 invocations of `operator+`, and each one creates two temporaries (one local, another to return the result by value without RVO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just considering too much, especially with the details of optimization.

For `result = a + b + c + d;`, the author just want to state that 3 temporaries will be created, the 1st one is for the result of `a + b`, then 2nd one is for the result of `temporary#1 + c`, the 3rd one is for `temporary#2 + d` and then it's assigned to `result`. After that, 3 temporaries are destroyed. All the temporaries are only used as the intermediate results.

On the other hand, some idioms such like [expression templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2598596/3309790) could make it possible to get the final result directly with elimination of temporaries.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but even with Expression templates you still have all the temporaries. That is the language syntax. With expression templates you just delay the computation to the very end (before the assignment).

Comment: @bolov (If my memory is accurate) suppose the `operator+` is implemented as `return Ratinal(lhs.numerator + rhs.numerator, lhs.denominator + rhs.denominator)`, then expression templates could expand `a + b + c + d` to `Ratinal(a.numerator + b.numerator + c.numerator + d.numerator, a.denominator + b.denominator + c.denominator + d.denominator`, at least we don't need 3 temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler may detect accumulation and apply optimizations but generally shifting and reducing an expression from left to right is somehow tricky as it may be hit by an expression of style a + b * c * d

It is more cautious to take approach of form:

> a + (b + (c + d))

which will not consume a variable before it might be required by an operator with higher priority. But evaluating it requires temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

No variables are created by the compiler. Because variables are those appearing in the source code, and **variables don't exist at execution time**, or in the executable (they might become memory locations, or be "ignored").

Read about the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). Compilers are often [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

See CppCon 2017 [Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid” talk](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `a+b+c+d` 6 temporaries will be created and destroyed, this is mandatory (with and without RVO). You can check it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/AUcPfs).

Inside `operator +` definition, in the expression `Rational(lhs)+=a`, the prvalue `Rational(lhs)` will be bound to the *implied object parameter* of `operator+=` which is authorized according to this very specific rule [[over.match.func]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.funcs#5.1) (refered in [[expr.call]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ref#4.3))

> even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter.

Then to bind a prvalue to a reference, temporary materialization must occurs [[class.temporary]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.temporary#2.1)

> Temporary objects are materialized [...]:
>
> - when binding a reference to a prvalue

So a temporary is created during the excution of each `operator +` call.

Then the expression `Rational(lhs)+=a` which once is returned can *conceptualy* seen as `Rational(Rational(lhs)+=a)` is a prvalue (a [prvalue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#1.2) is an *expression whose evaluation initializes an object* - phi:an object in power) which is then bound to the first argument of the 2 subsequent calls to `operator +`. The cited rule [class.temporary]/2.1 applies twice again and will create 2 temporaries:

1. One for materializing the result of `a+b`,
2. the other for materializing the result of `(a+b)+c`

So at this point 4 temporaries have been created. Then, the third call to `operator+` creates the 5th temporary inside the function body

Finaly the result of the last call to `operator +` is a *discarded value expression*. This last rule of the standard applies [class.temporary]/2.6:

> Temporary objects are materialized [...]:
>
> - when a prvalue appears as a discarded-value expression.

Which produces the 6th temporaries.

Without RVO the return value is directly materialized, which makes temporary materialization of the return prvalues not necessary anymore. This is why GCC produces the exact same assembly with and without `-fno-elide-constructors` compiler option.

In order to avoid temporary materialization, you could define `operator +`:

```
const Rational operator+(Rational lhs, const Rational& rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

With such a definition, the prvalue `a+b` and `(a+b)+c` would be directly used to initialize to first parameter of `operator +` which would save you from the materialization of 2 temporaries. See the assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/g/3mVswx).